# CSS Correct ways to zoom an background image

Tags: html, css, zooming

The CSS scale() function combined with a transition and transform on a div element with a background-image gets blurry, when I zoom in a high quality image.

What are better ways to zoom in high quality images in CSS (please only background propertys) with less blur ?

I use this CSS:

```
    .grow { transition: all 4s ease-in-out; }
    .grow:hover { transform: scale(2); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `background-size: 100%` to cover the entire container of the image. Then use `background-position` to pan and zoom to specific parts of the image